# I found this font in a book(Structural Steel Design written by Jack C McCormac and Stephen F Csernak), How can I know the type of font?

Tags: fonts

this is a screenshot of the book(Structural Steel Design written by Jack C McCormac and Stephen F Csernak):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting and it is something that I am often curious about myself. However, I am not sure of a way to do something like this in LaTeX or whether this is actually a LaTeX type question. Maybe studying/referencing something like this (https://practicaltypography.com/identifying-fonts.html) would be helpful.

Additionally, apps like [WhatTheFont](https://www.macworld.com/article/2886251/how-to-identify-a-font-any-font-anywhere-you-find-it.html) might also be helpful.